# Next.js: How to get applied styles from element?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Let's say I have global.css

```
.test {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

For some reason, I need to get the styles data from applied element. I tried refs but it always return empty string.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const divEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [divStyle, setDivStyle] = useState({} as CSSStyleDeclaration);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (divEl.current) {
      setDivStyle(divEl.current.style);
    }
  }, [divEl.current]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={divEl} className="test"></div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(divStyle, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
export default IndexPage;
```

Is it because next.js SSR or should I add something to dependency array?

code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/loone96/next-css/tree/main/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: The problem is that your styles are defined in that `test` class, but the `style` property returns only the inline style of an element, that is the style defined in the `style` HTML attribute.

Comment: @tromgy Thank you for your reply. What if I want to get the applied styled data from element? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *computed* styles to get what you need, although it won't be a "simple" object with properties. You'll need to query each property individually:

```
if (divEl.current) {
      setDivStyle(getComputedStyle(divEl.current));
    }
```

and then you can do something like:

```
divStyle.getPropertyValue("background-color")
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-yalow-urxiz?file=/pages/index.tsx:436-481) (forked from yours) that demostrates it.